# JS script for multiple select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

Please tell me there is a code that displays a search in select

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
```

```css
.select2-container{box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;margin:0;position:relative;vertical-align:middle}.select2-container .select2-selection--single{box-sizing:border-box;cursor:pointer;display:block;height:28px;user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none}.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered{display:block;padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap}.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear{position:relative}.select2-container[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered{padding-right:8px;padding-left:20px}.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple{box-sizing:border-box;cursor:pointer;display:block;min-height:32px;user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none}.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered{display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;padding-left:8px;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap}.select2-container .select2-search--inline{float:left}.select2-container .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field{box-sizing:border-box;border:none;font-size:100%;margin-top:5px;padding:0}.select2-container .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field::-webkit-search-cancel-button{-webkit-appearance:none}.select2-dropdown{background-color:white;border: 2px dashed #777777;border-radius:4px;box-sizing:border-box;display:block;position:absolute;left:-100000px;width:100%;z-index:1051}.select2-results{display:block}.select2-results__options{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}.select2-results__option{padding:6px;user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none}.select2-results__option[aria-selected]{cursor:pointer}.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown{left:0}.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown--above{border-bottom:none;border-bottom-left-radius:0;border-bottom-right-radius:0}.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown--below{border-top:none;border-top-left-radius:0;border-top-right-radius:0}.select2-search--dropdown{display:block;padding:4px}.select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field{padding:4px;width:100%;box-sizing:border-box}.select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field::-webkit-search-cancel-button{-webkit-appearance:none}.select2-search--dropdown.select2-search--hide{display:none}.select2-close-mask{border:0;margin:0;padding:0;display:block;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;min-height:100%;min-width:100%;height:auto;width:auto;opacity:0;z-index:99;background-color:#fff;filter:alpha(opacity=0)}.select2-hidden-accessible{border:0 !important;clip:rect(0 0 0 0) !important;-webkit-clip-path:inset(50%) !important;clip-path:inset(50%) !important;height:1px !important;overflow:hidden !important;padding:0 !important;position:absolute !important;width:1px !important;white-space:nowrap !important}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single{background-color:#fff;border: 2px dashed #777777;border-radius:4px}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered{color:#444;line-height:22px}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear{cursor:pointer;float:right;font-weight:bold}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__placeholder{color:#999}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow{height:26px;position:absolute;top:1px;right:1px;width:20px;display:none;}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b{border-color:#888 transparent transparent transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 4px 0 4px;height:0;left:50%;margin-left:-4px;margin-top:-2px;position:absolute;top:50%;width:0}.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear{float:left}.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow{left:1px;right:auto}.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--single{background-color:#eee;cursor:default}.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear{display:none}.select2-container--default.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b{border-color:transparent transparent #888 transparent;border-width:0 4px 5px 4px}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple{background-color:white;border:1px solid #aaa;border-radius:4px;cursor:text}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered{box-sizing:border-box;list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0 5px;width:100%}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered li{list-style:none}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__placeholder{color:#999;margin-top:5px;float:left}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__clear{cursor:pointer;float:right;font-weight:bold;margin-top:5px;margin-right:10px}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice{background-color:#e4e4e4;border:1px solid #aaa;border-radius:4px;cursor:default;float:left;margin-right:5px;margin-top:5px;padding:0 5px}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove{color:#999;cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;font-weight:bold;margin-right:2px}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove:hover{color:#333}.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice,.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__placeholder,.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-search--inline{float:right}.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice{margin-left:5px;margin-right:auto}.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove{margin-left:2px;margin-right:auto}.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple{border:solid black 1px;outline:0}.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--multiple{background-color:#eee;cursor:default}.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection__choice__remove{display:none}.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--single,.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--multiple{border-top-left-radius:0;border-top-right-radius:0}.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--single,.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--multiple{border-bottom-left-radius:0;border-bottom-right-radius:0}.select2-container--default .select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field{border:1px solid #777777;outline:none;}.select2-container--default .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field{background:transparent;border:none;outline:0;box-shadow:none;-webkit-appearance:textfield}.select2-container--default .select2-results>.select2-results__options{max-height:180px;overflow-y:hidden;}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[role=group]{padding:0}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true]{color:#999}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]{background-color:#e0e0e0;}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option{padding-left:1em}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__group{padding-left:0}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option{margin-left:-1em;padding-left:2em}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option{margin-left:-2em;padding-left:3em}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option{margin-left:-3em;padding-left:4em}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option{margin-left:-4em;padding-left:5em}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option{margin-left:-5em;padding-left:6em}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected]{background-color:#ffc600;color:white}.select2-container--default .select2-results__group{cursor:default;display:block;padding:6px}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single{background-color:#f7f7f7;border:1px solid #aaa;border-radius:4px;outline:0;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 50%, #eee 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 50%, #eee 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 50%, #eee 100%);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFEEEEEE', GradientType=0)}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single:focus{border:1px solid #5897fb}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered{color:#444;line-height:28px}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear{cursor:pointer;float:right;font-weight:bold;margin-right:10px}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__placeholder{color:#999}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow{background-color:#e0e0e0;border:none;border-left:1px solid #aaa;border-top-right-radius:4px;border-bottom-right-radius:4px;height:26px;position:absolute;top:1px;right:1px;width:20px;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee 50%, #ccc 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #eee 50%, #ccc 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee 50%, #ccc 100%);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFEEEEEE', endColorstr='#FFCCCCCC', GradientType=0)}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b{border-color:#888 transparent transparent transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 4px 0 4px;height:0;left:50%;margin-left:-4px;margin-top:-2px;position:absolute;top:50%;width:0}.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear{float:left}.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow{border:none;border-right:1px solid #aaa;border-radius:0;border-top-left-radius:4px;border-bottom-left-radius:4px;left:1px;right:auto}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single{border:1px solid #5897fb}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow{background:transparent;border:none}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b{border-color:transparent transparent #888 transparent;border-width:0 4px 5px 4px}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--single{border-top:none;border-top-left-radius:0;border-top-right-radius:0;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #eee 50%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #eee 50%);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #eee 50%);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFEEEEEE', GradientType=0)}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--single{border-bottom:none;border-bottom-left-radius:0;border-bottom-right-radius:0;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee 50%, #fff 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #eee 50%, #fff 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee 50%, #fff 100%);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFEEEEEE', endColorstr='#FFFFFFFF', GradientType=0)}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple{background-color:white;border:1px solid #aaa;border-radius:4px;cursor:text;outline:0}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple:focus{border:1px solid #5897fb}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0 5px}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__clear{display:none}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice{background-color:#e4e4e4;border:1px solid #aaa;border-radius:4px;cursor:default;float:left;margin-right:5px;margin-top:5px;padding:0 5px}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove{color:#888;cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;font-weight:bold;margin-right:2px}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove:hover{color:#555}.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice{float:right}.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice{margin-left:5px;margin-right:auto}.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove{margin-left:2px;margin-right:auto}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-selection--multiple{border:1px solid #5897fb}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--multiple{border-top:none;border-top-left-radius:0;border-top-right-radius:0}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--multiple{border-bottom:none;border-bottom-left-radius:0;border-bottom-right-radius:0}.select2-container--classic .select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field{border:1px solid #aaa;outline:0}.select2-container--classic .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field{outline:0;box-shadow:none}.select2-container--classic .select2-dropdown{background-color:#fff;border:1px solid transparent}.select2-container--classic .select2-dropdown--above{border-bottom:none}.select2-container--classic .select2-dropdown--below{border-top:none}.select2-container--classic .select2-results>.select2-results__options{max-height:200px;overflow-y:auto}.select2-container--classic .select2-results__option[role=group]{padding:0}.select2-container--classic .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true]{color:grey}.select2-container--classic .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected]{background-color:#3875d7;color:#fff}.select2-container--classic .select2-results__group{cursor:default;display:block;padding:6px}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown{border-color:#5897fb}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class='js-example-basic-single' id='ing' name='ing' style='width:228px;font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif!important;
 font-size:16px;height:35px;' required>
 <option value="asd">1</option>
  <option value="asd">2</option>
  <option value="asd">3</option></select>
  
  <select class='js-example-basic-single' id='ing' name='ing' style='width:228px;font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif!important;
 font-size:16px;height:35px;' required>
 <option value="asd">4</option>
  <option value="asd">5</option>
  <option value="asd">6</option></select>
```

Why only one select works and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you used the same `id="ing"` for both `<select>`. IDs are supposed to be unique, and this apparently confused the `select2` plugin.

I changed the second one to `id="ing2"` and now they both work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
```

```css
.select2-container{box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;margin:0;position:relative;vertical-align:middle}.select2-container .select2-selection--single{box-sizing:border-box;cursor:pointer;display:block;height:28px;user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none}.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered{display:block;padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap}.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear{position:relative}.select2-container[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered{padding-right:8px;padding-left:20px}.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple{box-sizing:border-box;cursor:pointer;display:block;min-height:32px;user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none}.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered{display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;padding-left:8px;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap}.select2-container .select2-search--inline{float:left}.select2-container .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field{box-sizing:border-box;border:none;font-size:100%;margin-top:5px;padding:0}.select2-container .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field::-webkit-search-cancel-button{-webkit-appearance:none}.select2-dropdown{background-color:white;border: 2px dashed #777777;border-radius:4px;box-sizing:border-box;display:block;position:absolute;left:-100000px;width:100%;z-index:1051}.select2-results{display:block}.select2-results__options{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}.select2-results__option{padding:6px;user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none}.select2-results__option[aria-selected]{cursor:pointer}.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown{left:0}.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown--above{border-bottom:none;border-bottom-left-radius:0;border-bottom-right-radius:0}.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown--below{border-top:none;border-top-left-radius:0;border-top-right-radius:0}.select2-search--dropdown{display:block;padding:4px}.select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field{padding:4px;width:100%;box-sizing:border-box}.select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field::-webkit-search-cancel-button{-webkit-appearance:none}.select2-search--dropdown.select2-search--hide{display:none}.select2-close-mask{border:0;margin:0;padding:0;display:block;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;min-height:100%;min-width:100%;height:auto;width:auto;opacity:0;z-index:99;background-color:#fff;filter:alpha(opacity=0)}.select2-hidden-accessible{border:0 !important;clip:rect(0 0 0 0) !important;-webkit-clip-path:inset(50%) !important;clip-path:inset(50%) !important;height:1px !important;overflow:hidden !important;padding:0 !important;position:absolute !important;width:1px !important;white-space:nowrap !important}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single{background-color:#fff;border: 2px dashed #777777;border-radius:4px}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered{color:#444;line-height:22px}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear{cursor:pointer;float:right;font-weight:bold}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__placeholder{color:#999}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow{height:26px;position:absolute;top:1px;right:1px;width:20px;display:none;}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b{border-color:#888 transparent transparent transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 4px 0 4px;height:0;left:50%;margin-left:-4px;margin-top:-2px;position:absolute;top:50%;width:0}.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear{float:left}.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow{left:1px;right:auto}.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--single{background-color:#eee;cursor:default}.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear{display:none}.select2-container--default.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b{border-color:transparent transparent #888 transparent;border-width:0 4px 5px 4px}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple{background-color:white;border:1px solid #aaa;border-radius:4px;cursor:text}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered{box-sizing:border-box;list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0 5px;width:100%}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered li{list-style:none}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__placeholder{color:#999;margin-top:5px;float:left}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__clear{cursor:pointer;float:right;font-weight:bold;margin-top:5px;margin-right:10px}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice{background-color:#e4e4e4;border:1px solid #aaa;border-radius:4px;cursor:default;float:left;margin-right:5px;margin-top:5px;padding:0 5px}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove{color:#999;cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;font-weight:bold;margin-right:2px}.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove:hover{color:#333}.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice,.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__placeholder,.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-search--inline{float:right}.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice{margin-left:5px;margin-right:auto}.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove{margin-left:2px;margin-right:auto}.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple{border:solid black 1px;outline:0}.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--multiple{background-color:#eee;cursor:default}.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection__choice__remove{display:none}.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--single,.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--multiple{border-top-left-radius:0;border-top-right-radius:0}.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--single,.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--multiple{border-bottom-left-radius:0;border-bottom-right-radius:0}.select2-container--default .select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field{border:1px solid #777777;outline:none;}.select2-container--default .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field{background:transparent;border:none;outline:0;box-shadow:none;-webkit-appearance:textfield}.select2-container--default .select2-results>.select2-results__options{max-height:180px;overflow-y:hidden;}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[role=group]{padding:0}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true]{color:#999}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]{background-color:#e0e0e0;}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option{padding-left:1em}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__group{padding-left:0}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option{margin-left:-1em;padding-left:2em}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option{margin-left:-2em;padding-left:3em}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option{margin-left:-3em;padding-left:4em}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option{margin-left:-4em;padding-left:5em}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option{margin-left:-5em;padding-left:6em}.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected]{background-color:#ffc600;color:white}.select2-container--default .select2-results__group{cursor:default;display:block;padding:6px}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single{background-color:#f7f7f7;border:1px solid #aaa;border-radius:4px;outline:0;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 50%, #eee 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 50%, #eee 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 50%, #eee 100%);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFEEEEEE', GradientType=0)}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single:focus{border:1px solid #5897fb}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered{color:#444;line-height:28px}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear{cursor:pointer;float:right;font-weight:bold;margin-right:10px}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__placeholder{color:#999}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow{background-color:#e0e0e0;border:none;border-left:1px solid #aaa;border-top-right-radius:4px;border-bottom-right-radius:4px;height:26px;position:absolute;top:1px;right:1px;width:20px;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee 50%, #ccc 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #eee 50%, #ccc 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee 50%, #ccc 100%);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFEEEEEE', endColorstr='#FFCCCCCC', GradientType=0)}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b{border-color:#888 transparent transparent transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 4px 0 4px;height:0;left:50%;margin-left:-4px;margin-top:-2px;position:absolute;top:50%;width:0}.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear{float:left}.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow{border:none;border-right:1px solid #aaa;border-radius:0;border-top-left-radius:4px;border-bottom-left-radius:4px;left:1px;right:auto}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single{border:1px solid #5897fb}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow{background:transparent;border:none}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b{border-color:transparent transparent #888 transparent;border-width:0 4px 5px 4px}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--single{border-top:none;border-top-left-radius:0;border-top-right-radius:0;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #eee 50%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #eee 50%);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #eee 50%);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFEEEEEE', GradientType=0)}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--single{border-bottom:none;border-bottom-left-radius:0;border-bottom-right-radius:0;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee 50%, #fff 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #eee 50%, #fff 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee 50%, #fff 100%);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFEEEEEE', endColorstr='#FFFFFFFF', GradientType=0)}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple{background-color:white;border:1px solid #aaa;border-radius:4px;cursor:text;outline:0}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple:focus{border:1px solid #5897fb}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0 5px}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__clear{display:none}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice{background-color:#e4e4e4;border:1px solid #aaa;border-radius:4px;cursor:default;float:left;margin-right:5px;margin-top:5px;padding:0 5px}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove{color:#888;cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;font-weight:bold;margin-right:2px}.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove:hover{color:#555}.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice{float:right}.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice{margin-left:5px;margin-right:auto}.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove{margin-left:2px;margin-right:auto}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-selection--multiple{border:1px solid #5897fb}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--multiple{border-top:none;border-top-left-radius:0;border-top-right-radius:0}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--multiple{border-bottom:none;border-bottom-left-radius:0;border-bottom-right-radius:0}.select2-container--classic .select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field{border:1px solid #aaa;outline:0}.select2-container--classic .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field{outline:0;box-shadow:none}.select2-container--classic .select2-dropdown{background-color:#fff;border:1px solid transparent}.select2-container--classic .select2-dropdown--above{border-bottom:none}.select2-container--classic .select2-dropdown--below{border-top:none}.select2-container--classic .select2-results>.select2-results__options{max-height:200px;overflow-y:auto}.select2-container--classic .select2-results__option[role=group]{padding:0}.select2-container--classic .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true]{color:grey}.select2-container--classic .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected]{background-color:#3875d7;color:#fff}.select2-container--classic .select2-results__group{cursor:default;display:block;padding:6px}.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown{border-color:#5897fb}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class='js-example-basic-single' id='ing' name='ing' style='width:228px;font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif!important;
 font-size:16px;height:35px;' required>
 <option value="asd">1</option>
  <option value="asd">2</option>
  <option value="asd">3</option></select>
  
  <select class='js-example-basic-single' id='ing2' name='ing' style='width:228px;font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif!important;
 font-size:16px;height:35px;' required>
 <option value="asd">4</option>
  <option value="asd">5</option>
  <option value="asd">6</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

change  input's id and name....

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
```

```css
.select2-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--single {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 28px;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear {
  position: relative
}

.select2-container[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  min-height: 32px;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 8px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.select2-container .select2-search--inline {
  float: left
}

.select2-container .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 0
}

.select2-container .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none
}

.select2-dropdown {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px dashed #777777;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1051
}

.select2-results {
  display: block
}

.select2-results__options {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.select2-results__option {
  padding: 6px;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none
}

.select2-results__option[aria-selected] {
  cursor: pointer
}

.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown {
  left: 0
}

.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown--above {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0
}

.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown--below {
  border-top: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0
}

.select2-search--dropdown {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px
}

.select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field {
  padding: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none
}

.select2-search--dropdown.select2-search--hide {
  display: none
}

.select2-close-mask {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: #fff;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0)
}

.select2-hidden-accessible {
  border: 0 !important;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0) !important;
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%) !important;
  clip-path: inset(50%) !important;
  height: 1px !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 1px !important;
  white-space: nowrap !important
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px dashed #777777;
  border-radius: 4px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
  color: #444;
  line-height: 22px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__placeholder {
  color: #999
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
  height: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  width: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b {
  border-color: #888 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 4px 0 4px;
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 0
}

.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear {
  float: left
}

.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
  left: 1px;
  right: auto
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--single {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: default
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear {
  display: none
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b {
  border-color: transparent transparent #888 transparent;
  border-width: 0 4px 5px 4px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: text
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 100%
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered li {
  list-style: none
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__placeholder {
  color: #999;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: left
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__clear {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: default;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 0 5px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove {
  color: #999;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 2px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove:hover {
  color: #333
}

.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice,
.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__placeholder,
.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-search--inline {
  float: right
}

.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: auto
}

.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove {
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: auto
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple {
  border: solid black 1px;
  outline: 0
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--multiple {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: default
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection__choice__remove {
  display: none
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--single,
.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--multiple {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--single,
.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--multiple {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0
}

.select2-container--default .select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field {
  border: 1px solid #777777;
  outline: none;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results>.select2-results__options {
  max-height: 180px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[role=group] {
  padding: 0
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true] {
  color: #999
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
  padding-left: 1em
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__group {
  padding-left: 0
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
  margin-left: -1em;
  padding-left: 2em
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
  margin-left: -2em;
  padding-left: 3em
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
  margin-left: -3em;
  padding-left: 4em
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
  margin-left: -4em;
  padding-left: 5em
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
  margin-left: -5em;
  padding-left: 6em
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected] {
  background-color: #ffc600;
  color: white
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__group {
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 50%, #eee 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 50%, #eee 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 50%, #eee 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFEEEEEE', GradientType=0)
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single:focus {
  border: 1px solid #5897fb
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
  color: #444;
  line-height: 28px
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__placeholder {
  color: #999
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  height: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  width: 20px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee 50%, #ccc 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eee 50%, #ccc 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee 50%, #ccc 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFEEEEEE', endColorstr='#FFCCCCCC', GradientType=0)
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b {
  border-color: #888 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 4px 0 4px;
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 0
}

.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear {
  float: left
}

.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
  border: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  left: 1px;
  right: auto
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single {
  border: 1px solid #5897fb
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
  background: transparent;
  border: none
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b {
  border-color: transparent transparent #888 transparent;
  border-width: 0 4px 5px 4px
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--single {
  border-top: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #eee 50%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #eee 50%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #eee 50%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFEEEEEE', GradientType=0)
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--single {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee 50%, #fff 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eee 50%, #fff 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee 50%, #fff 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFEEEEEE', endColorstr='#FFFFFFFF', GradientType=0)
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: text;
  outline: 0
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple:focus {
  border: 1px solid #5897fb
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 5px
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__clear {
  display: none
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: default;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 0 5px
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 2px
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove:hover {
  color: #555
}

.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
  float: right
}

.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: auto
}

.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove {
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: auto
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-selection--multiple {
  border: 1px solid #5897fb
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--multiple {
  border-top: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--multiple {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  outline: 0
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-dropdown {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-dropdown--above {
  border-bottom: none
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-dropdown--below {
  border-top: none
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-results>.select2-results__options {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-results__option[role=group] {
  padding: 0
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true] {
  color: grey
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected] {
  background-color: #3875d7;
  color: #fff
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-results__group {
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown {
  border-color: #5897fb
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class='js-example-basic-single' id='ing' name='ing' style='width:228px;font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif!important;
 font-size:16px;height:35px;' required>
  <option value="asd">1</option>
  <option value="asd">2</option>
  <option value="asd">3</option>
</select>

<select class='js-example-basic-single' id='ing2' name='ing2' style='width:228px;font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif!important;
 font-size:16px;height:35px;' required>
  <option value="asd">4</option>
  <option value="asd">5</option>
  <option value="asd">6</option>
</select>
```